# GraphError: Subscription validation request failed. Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to validation request

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I've been working on implementing Microsoft Graph webhook subscriptions in my application, and I've run into an issue with subscription validation. Whenever I attempt to validate the subscription, I receive the following error message:

GraphError: Subscription validation request failed. Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to validation request.

Here's a snippet of my code that handles the validation request:

```
@Post('event')

async eventWebhook(@Req() req, @Res() res) {

    if (req.query && req.query.validationToken) {

        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

        res.send(200, req.query.validationToken);

        return;

    }

    //... other logics to handle events

}
```

Additionally, I've used the official Postman collection provided by Microsoft to simulate the validation request, and it appears to work correctly. Here's the Postman request and response:

Postman Request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'api.com/event?validationToken=somethin'
```

Postman Response:

```
200 OK | 641 ms | 312 B

body : somethin
```

However, when I run my application on the server and attempt to set up a subscription through Microsoft Graph, I consistently encounter the validation error mentioned above.

I've verified the following:

The endpoint URL matches exactly with what I've specified in the subscription setup.
There are no network or firewall issues; the server is publicly accessible.
Middleware and routing do not interfere with the validation request.
There are no unexpected headers in the response.
The server configuration for handling POST requests is correct.

```
GraphError: Subscription validation request failed. Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to validation request.

    at new GraphError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/GraphError.js:34:28)

    at Function.GraphErrorHandler.constructErrorFromResponse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/GraphErrorHandler.js:63:22)

    at Function.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/GraphErrorHandler.js:91:48)

    at step (/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:193:27)

    at Object.next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:174:57)

    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:167:75

    at new Promise (<anonymous>)

    at Object.__awaiter (/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:163:16)

    at Function.GraphErrorHandler.getError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/GraphErrorHandler.js:87:24)

    at GraphRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/GraphRequest.js:315:84) {

  statusCode: 400,

  code: 'InvalidRequest',

  requestId: 'uuid',

  date: Date obj,

  body: '{"code":"InvalidRequest","message":"Subscription validation request failed. Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to validation request.","innerError":{"date":"Date obj","request-id":"uuid","client-request-id":"uuid

  headers: Headers {

    [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] {

      'cache-control': [Array],

      'transfer-encoding': [Array],

      'content-type': [Array],

      'content-encoding': [Array],

      vary: [Array],

      'strict-transport-security': [Array],

      'request-id': [Array],

      'client-request-id': [Array],

      'x-ms-ags-diagnostic': [Array],

      date: [Array],

      connection: [Array]

    }

  }
```

I'm unsure why the validation request fails in my application but works with Postman. Can anyone offer guidance on what could be causing this issue or suggest potential solutions?

Comment: What does your server log say? Does it show that status 200 was returned, or perhaps is there an error?

Comment: Also, did you use the [Postman test collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman) the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery-webhooks?tabs=http#notificationurl-validation) suggest (the `notificationUrl` case in the `Misc` folder in the Postman collection)? Does it succeed?

Comment: Yes postman collection request I've already mentioned the response above ( i used curl based on that collection )

Comment: Server log is 200 in case of post man collection but when microsoft sends a request it goes : Subscription validation request failed.

Comment: "subscription validation request failed" sound alike Microsoft's response. What does your server log say?

Comment: I've added the full error log that server is throwing, nothing helpful here I guess

Comment: That's not the log I meant. I meant the log of the validation endpoint.

Comment: Well that's the problem there is no validation error nor is any body log I've put a logger before any of my logic *mentioned above* but there's non

Comment: What do you mean by "body log"? I'm talking about your HTTP server access log, which would show any requests received and what status code was returned. Does it show the validation request?

Comment: By body log I meant the request reaching the app, I'll set-up a logger before the app to see all the request and see what I can find, but that request.body logger doesn't printout anything for that microsoft 200 error, when I send a request by postman it does, like microsoft is not sending any request before that error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a PM on Microsoft Graph Change Notifications team.

If Postman works, then unintentional application encoding is likely culprit. There is a chance that there is something in the encoding that your application is using that may alter the response being sent  Can you view the response you're sending to determine encoding?

Comment: Yes The problem was nginx was unintentionally/missconfigured altering the incoming request, updating that resolved the Issue